Prove that a $d$-simplex has a nonempty interior directly.
I want to show that the $d$-simplex has nonempty interior in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The $d$-simplex is defined to be the set
$$S=\left\{\theta_0\mathbf{u_0}+\ldots+\theta_d\mathbf{u}_d\,:\,\sum_{k=0}^d\theta_k=1\text{ and }\theta_k\geq 0\,\forall 0\leq k\leq d.\right\},$$
where $\mathbf{u}_1-\mathbf{u}_0, \ldots, \mathbf{u}_d-\mathbf{u}_0$ are linearly independent.
I know there are already some responses to this, but I want to physically construct a point $\mathbf{x}\in S$ and a radius $r$ such that $B(\mathbf{x}, r)\subseteq S$, where we use the Euclidean norm for the ball. None of the other responses specifically address this, and I am trying to construct an explicit ball. The only thing I tried is to look at
$$\mathbf{x}=\frac{1}{d+1}\mathbf{u}_0+\ldots+\frac{1}{d+1}\mathbf{u}_d$$ and look at $\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{u}$, where $\|\mathbf{u}\|_2<\varepsilon$, and see where that leads me, but the issue is regular vector addition doesn't have a great way of showing how it affects the constants $\theta_0, \ldots, \theta_d$, unless there's something I don't know of.
I would love for some help. Please don't suggest any other way, I need a response in terms of a center and a radius, since I am compiling notes on optimization that needs nothing more than basic real analysis.

You can do some labour intensive work to find a suitable radius from the barycenter (the point you mention in the question). Find all the distances from this point to the faces of the simplex, then take any distance smaller than the minimum of them. Or if you are happy with just existence (I believe you are not), show that the barycenter is not on the boundary of the simplex.

Hi. Thanks for the response. I would in fact be content with existence. However, I would need to prove that the boundary of $S$ (i.e. the set of points where every ball intersects both $S$ and its complement) is actually the set of points where at least one coefficient is 0.

I believe you can show that by first showing that the simplex is the set of points that are formed by the intersection of exactly those half-planes. Then by looking at what the boundary of a half-plane means, you can get your result.

Note that while deriving explicit points, radius, etc, is a worthwhile exercise, it complicates an answer somewhat, so if this is for pedagogical purposes, one might be better off working at a less granular level. For example, it is easier to work with $u_0=0, u_k = e_k$ to derive an estimate, and the $\sup$ norm a little easier.

The key here is that $u_0,...,u_d$ are affinely independent. That is, if $\sum_k \lambda_k u_k =0$ and $\sum_k \lambda_k = 0$, then $\lambda_k = 0$. In particular, the matrix $\bar{U} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &\ \cdots & 1 \\ u_0 & \cdots & u_d \end{bmatrix}$ is invertible.
Let $U = \begin{bmatrix} u_0 & \cdots & u_d \end{bmatrix}$. Pick any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $\lambda = \bar{U}^{-1} \binom{1}{x}$. (The $\lambda_k$ are the barycentric coordinates of $x$ in terms of the $u_k$.) Note that $\sum_k \lambda_k = 1$, $U \lambda = x$ and the map $\Lambda x = \bar{U}^{-1} \binom{1}{x}$ is linear, hence continuous. (The essential point here is that $\sum_k [\Lambda x]_k = 1$, so the 'sum to one' condition holds automatically.)
Let $\hat{u} = \sum_k {1 \over 1+d} u_k$ and note that $\hat{u} \in S$ and $[\Lambda \hat{u}]_k = {1 \over 1+d}>0$. By continuity of $\Lambda$, there is an open set $V$ containing $\hat{u}$ such that $[\Lambda u]_k >0$ for all $u \in V$ and so $u \in S$, or equivalently $V \subset S$.
To get an answer in terms of the Euclidean norm, consider finding a ball around $0$ such that $[\Lambda (\hat{u}+h)]_k >0$ for all $h$ in the ball. Note that if $\|\Lambda\|_\infty \|h\|_\infty < {1 \over 1+d}$, then $[\Lambda (\hat{u}+h)]_k = [\Lambda \hat{u}]_k+ [\Lambda h]_k \ge {1 \over 1+d} - \|\Lambda\|_\infty \|h\|_\infty>0$. In particular, every element of the $\sup$ norm ball $B_\infty(\hat{u}, {1 \over (1+d)\|\Lambda\|_\infty})$ will work.
Since $B_2(\hat{u}, {1 \over (1+d)\|\Lambda\|_\infty})\subset B_\infty(\hat{u}, {1 \over (1+d)\|\Lambda\|_\infty})$, a center of $\hat{u}$ and radius ${1 \over (1+d)\|\Lambda\|_\infty}$ will suffice.
